# Coloring each word in inner HTML with a separate color using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a small project to color each syllable in a separate color.

We take input from a text area and then pass it to a JavaScript function that does the syllable splitting and finally we need to output each syllable in a different color.

At first I wanted to output the result in another text area, but then I found out that there is no way to style each syllable inside a text area.

So for now I will be outputting it in a div using inner HTML.

This is a sample code that I am using to test what works and what doesn't:

I tried changing the inner HTML style before outputting each result but it is not working. I am getting both words in blue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Username Password Generator</title>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">



<form id="myForm">
  First name:<br> <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"/><br>
  Last name:<br> <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"/><br>
 
</form> 
<br>
<button onclick="color()">color</button> 

<h1 id="firstNameLastName"></h1>

<script>

  function color() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[1].value;

 //var password = randomstring();
  document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").innerHTML = firstName;
  document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").style.color = "blue";
  document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").innerHTML += ' ' + lastName;
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I updated my function and now it works:

```js
  function color() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[1].value;

 //var password = randomstring();
  var x = document.createElement("SPAN");
  x.style.color="red";
  var t = document.createTextNode(firstName);
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").appendChild(x);
  x = document.createElement("SPAN");
  x.style.color="blue";
  t = document.createTextNode(lastName);
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").appendChild(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will not work. You will need separate `html` elements for each word. I think a `span` would be a good choice.

The reason is that when you do `document.getElementById("firstNameLastName").style.color` you set the text color for the whole `h1` element.

You initially make it all red, and then all blue, so you end up with 2 blue words.

You can check my approach on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/y71zcguo/).

Comment: I wanted to go with the span approach however I wasn't able to find the correct syntax to do so. I would really appreciate if you could show me the right syntax for this approach using the above code

Comment: @ymho Since you are doing this to learn, me giving you the answer won't help much. Update your answer with the code you are trying and I will try to point you to the right direction without actually just giving  you the code.

Comment: You are right ! Thank u for that. I actually did a bit of research just now and found out a DOM manipulation method that could satisfy my need (var x = document.createElement("SPAN");)
I will be testing it and will update my code once it works.
Thanks again

Comment: I updated my answer with the code I will be using. However, I have one more question regarding the best practice. Is it good that I am overriding the x and t vars each time ? I did that because I don't want to keep on creating more and more variables that I won't be using later on

Comment: @ymho I cannot understand who would downvote my answer, it is correct plus I tried to help. Anyway. To answer your question, when you only use two variables in your script, no, you absolutely don't have to worry about that. However, your code could be way more readable. Plus, what happens when you have 3 or more words?

Comment: @ymho To demonstrate how you could solve these problems, I created a fiddle and added it to my answer. I would suggest trying to solve it yourself before opening the link. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand who would downvote it as well. I found your input very helpful.
Anyways, I applied this code to my application ( which is not the code I provided in the question, I didn't upload my code because it is really long) 
It does not matter how many words there is, in my code there is a while loop that is going over the user input and each iteration, I am overriding the variables again

Comment: thanks again. I solved the issue I was facing in my project and I will be submitting it tomorrow. 
Thank you for your help @anpel 
I upvoted ur answer however because I am a new user it did not count

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<form id="myForm">
  First name:<br> <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"/><br>
  Last name:<br> <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"/><br>
 
</form> 
<br>
<button onclick="color()">color</button> 
<span id="name"></span>
```

```
function color() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[1].value;
  
  
    var firstNameSpan = "<span> my firstname: "+ firstName + "</span>";
    var lastNameSpan = "<span> my firstname: "+ lastName + "</span>";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = firstNameSpan + " " + lastName;
}
```

Comment: Hey yes this could work in the context of the code I provided in my question. However, my actual code is dealing with a much bigger text that varies depending on the user's input.
So I won't be able to use this, as this approach creates a static amount of spans

Comment: I've edited the original answer. You can create spans by loop and set them to `name` span.